# Two arrayLists, each object to have their own List

Tags: java, arraylist

I am absolutely clueless atm on how to achieve what I want here. So I want each of these customers that I create to have their own list with account number(s) but i dont seem to get it to work correctly as it seems like each customer does not have an unique "accountList". Any tips or pointers? Thanks in advance!

## Bank.java

```
List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
case 1:
// creates a new customer, adds customer to arraylist
    System.out.println("Type name:");
    String firstname = input.next();

    System.out.println("Type surname:");
    String surname = input.next();

    System.out.println("Type your social security number:");
    ssn = input.next();

    System.out.println("Input account number: ");
    String accNo = input.next();

    Account account = new Account(accNo);
    Customer newCustomer = new Customer(firstname,
    surname, ssn, account);
    customerList.add(newCustomer);
```

## Customer.java

```
public class Customer {
    public List<Account> accountList;
    private String firstname, surname, ssn;
    Account account;

    public Customer(String firstname, String surname, String ssn, Account account) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.account = account;
    this.accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
}

// set and get methods here (not relevant I think)

public void addAccount(Account account) {
    this.accountList.add(account);
}
```

## Account.java

```
public class Account {
    private String accountNo;

    public Account(String accountNo) {
            this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }

    public void setAccountNo(String accountNo) {
            this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }

    public String getAccountNo() {
            return accountNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no obvious issues with this code. Could you post the output and expected output describing your error?

Comment: What behavior in your program makes you think that each customer doesn't have their own account list?

Comment: Also, why do you need both List<Account> and Account in Customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Customers already have their own list of accounts.
Since 'accountList' is defined as object-instance variable, each Customer created will have its own, independant list of accounts.

All of your customers would only share this list if you add the 'static' keyword and make it a class variable (e.g. no matter how many Customers you create there will only be this one list).

I however recomend you have two changes:

1.) Remove the Account variable from Customer. Since you have a list containing all of those Accounts i dont see any sence in having a single Account attached to that Customer (unless it is some sort of Main-Account or similar but in that case it would differ from the ones in the list by its type).

2.) To still be able to handle a Account from within your Customer id change the constructor like this:

```
public Customer(String firstname, String surname, String ssn, Account account) {
this.firstname = firstname;
this.surname = surname;
this.ssn = ssn;
this.accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();

//directly add the first account to the list of accounts
if(account != null){
    accountList.add(account);
}
```

3.) (Optional) Above Constructor is not satisfying. If someone would have a Account-Object ready when it comes to creating your Customer, there is also a high chance said caller (in the end it is you ;)) has a whole bunch of Accounts to add to this Customer, so id change my Constructor like this:

```
    public Customer(String firstname, String surname, String ssn, List<Account> accounts) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();

    //directly add the first account
    if(accounts != null){
        this.accountList = accounts;
    }
}
```

If a caller has a List of Accounts for this Customer he can directly deliver the entire List on Object creation. If on the other hand he has not yet any Accounts ready he will just deliver null and you have an empty list ready.

There is also the possibility of "varargs" (variable arguments) allowing to come up with 0-n arguments of a certain type if you dont like above "null" if no Accounts are ready:

```
public Customer(String firstname, String surname, String ssn,
        Account... accounts) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();

    // If any accounts delivered, add them to the list
    for (Account tempAccount : accounts) {
        if (tempAccount != null) {
            accountList.add(tempAccount);
        }
    }
}
```

In this example you can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){


    // Case "I dont have a Account yet, just make me a Customer!
    Customer myCustomer = new Customer("Foo", "Bar", "bla");

    // Case "I already have a Account, letme directly add that to the Customer that i want to create now"
    Account a = new Account();
    Customer myCustomer2 = new Customer("Foo", "Bar", "bla", a);

    // Case "I already have a list of Accounts, letme directly add that to ..."
    Account b = new Account();
    Account c = new Account();
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    accounts.add(b);
    accounts.add(c);

    Customer myCustomer3 = new Customer("Foo", "Bar", "bla", accounts.toArray(new Account[0]));
}
```

Sorry i began writing about the varargs before i noticed you need a Array of Objects and not a List. That is why we have the "toArray"-Method as a Workaround that makes our List of Accounts to a Array of Accounts. But dont hesitate to just ignore the part about varargs if its not clear and go for the Constructor taking a List of Accounts (or null).

I assume you are learning Java and if so: Youre doing good so far. Dont get confused by all the informations and keep on. I recommend you read about object-instance-variables and class variables to clarify what objects share and what not. The "better" Design will come with the years, dont bother about such "design issues" right now and play with them since they will teach you "the hard way".